# How do I properly bundle a feature in aurelia?

Tags: aurelia

I am stuck with the following issue:

I have created a small feature with the following index.js for configuration:

```js
export function configure(config) {
  config
    .globalResources('./input/GuiCssSize', './input/GuiDropdown', './input/GuiColorpicker')
}
```

It works fine in unbundled mode. But when I bundle, it won't find the requested files (e.g. GuiCssSize).

So what steps do I have to make, to include this feature with all dependencies into my bundle?

Any hint appreciated.

Comment: Make sure those files are included in a bundle. Check the bundled output to confirm that those modules made it in, and that they are named what you'd expect when calling them.

Comment: @Andrew covers it - if you can supply your `bundle.js` config file we may be able to help.

Comment: I think I have messed a little too much with my packaging task runner. I'm investigating right now. I will post again if I have more insights... Thanks for your support

Comment: Which bundler do you use? For new aurelia webpack plugin you have to wrap modules in `PLATFORM.moduleName` so `'./input/GuiCssSize'` becomes `PLATFORM.moduleName('./input/GuiCssSize')`